# Sorting points in trigonometric order in 3d space

Tags: math

I have three points in 3d space A,B,C. The points are not collinear. I wish to sort the points in such a way that if I traverse them I would traverse the triangle ABC in trigonometric(counterclockwise) order.

Comment: This doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Alexandre C. why exactly? There are several solutions, but I don't see why it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @static_rtti: You need 4 points to even remotely make sense of the sentence (to define an orientation). It is as if you were asking to traverse 2 points in the plane in trigonometric order.

Comment: @Alexandre: I see. I was thinking that a triangle in the plane does have an orientation, but in space, you have to chose from which way you look at it :)

Comment: 3 points: there are 2 cycles.  Each is clockwise depending on the projection.  So, do whatever you wish, and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define which side of the triangle you are looking at. The ordering that is counter-clockwise (CCW) will be clockwise (CW) when viewed from the other side of the triangle.

You can pick any order ABC and then compute the cross product (A-C)x(B-C) which will give you a vector normal to the plane of the triangle. The direction it points (up or down) will depend on the ordering you've chosen. If its the wrong order you may reverse your ordering or swap two points.

The key is to figure out which side you are going to view it from before talking about direction.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have only 6 possible orderings, I would go for the brute force approach: for each ordering, check if it satisfies your constraint, and if it does, chose it.

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to check my constraint.

Comment: That's because your constraint isn't well defined; see Alexandre's comments.